# GLSL. Can someone explain why gl_FragCoord.xy / screenSize is performed and for what reason?

Tags: opengl, shader, glsl

I'm new to shaders and know that you can color pixels with gl_FragColor but sometimes there is this thing:

```
vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / screenSize; // or resolution or smthn depends on the implementation
```

If gl_FragCoord is like pixel coordinates, what does **uv** get?

Why is it often done in GLSL?

If someone could even draw an example of which part of the screen will be UV it will be very helpful!

Comment: It is important to note that the Rasterization stage before the optional Fragment Shader performs fragment attribute interpolation **and** viewport transformation for the `gl_FragCoord` attribute.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First, `gl_FragCoord.xy` are screen space coordinates of current pixel based on viewport size. So if viewport size is `width=5`, `height=4` then each fragment contains:

[image]

Why are uvs needed? For example I rendered geometry to screen quad and then I need to apply some postprocessing on this quad in another rendering pass. To sample from that quad I need texture coordinates in range [0, 1]. So to calculate them I perform division `gl_FragCoord.xy / viewPortSize`.

Comment: It might be worth saying that `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB` doesn't use normalized coordinates, but that `GL_TEXTURE_*D` textures do.

Answer (score 6):

Refer to narthex's excellent answer for details and example, but simply put,

If you want to *map* the pixel coordinate values to the range **0** to **1** , you divide by viewPortSize.